# Redirect / Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directus

I'm trying to host directus on a shared hoster but i can't get it to work.
I want to set it up in a subdomain and set the root of the subdomain to the root of directus. Then i placed a .htaccess file in the root folder with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/
</IfModule>
```

so when i open cms.domain.com i get redirected to cms.domain.com/public. On my local machine where i have complete access this works, but on the hosted server i get 404 when redirected to cms.domain.com/public.
When navigating to cms.domain.com/public without this .htaccess i get a 500 internal server error which, again, does not happen on my local machine with the exact same configuration.

In the public folder is another .htaccess-file (from directus itself) with this content:

```
# Comment this line if you are getting: "Option SymLinksIfOwnerMatch not allowed here" error in Apache
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# php5_module automatically handles HTTP_AUTHORIZATION headers, but fcgi_module does not.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Map all admin endpoints to the admin app (except static files)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)   admin/index.html [NC,L]

    # Map all other requests to invoke the API router (except static files)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule !^admin index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</ifModule>

# Uncomment the following lines to modify PHP settings. The lines below can be used to increase the max upload size of files in Directus
#<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  #php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
  #php_value post_max_size 100M
#</IfModule>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: The error logs will tell you what is going on.  A guess, **line 1** `RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/` and **line 2** `RewriteRule !^admin index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` conflict.  The `RewriteCond` before says that any request which is not a file, should go to index.php, but you want it to go to /public/ as well.

Comment: You should check your error log for details of the 500 error. This is quite likely a rewrite loop, however, this would seemingly only occur if `/public/index.php` (or `/public/admin/index.html`) do not exist? However, `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive, not mod_rewrite - do you really want to expose the `/public` subdirectory and have this as part of the URL?